# Naming conventions and grammar

Tags: naming-conventions, naming

I'm curious to know about rules for grammar-related/english-related naming properties (not about capitalization etc).

What is recomended way to name class property (for public API): DateEnd or EndDate?

DateEnd approach allows to find more easily and group related properties (intellisense & docs):
DateStart, DateEnd ... 
But we don't use names like IdTask, TypeProperty. We use TaskId and PropertyType. And the last ones are more grammatically correct.

So why googling shows that both ways used ~ 50/50? microsoft use both in public APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Following convention, and often grammar, is useful in making an API intuitive and memorable.
As you suggest, TaskId is more common than IdTask, so should be preferred.

Grouping related properties is a useful bonus if it doesn't make the property name too obscure.

Using the [Exchange Web Services Task element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563930%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx) as an example, reminder properties are grouped as they start with "Reminder", for example

- ReminderDueBy
- ReminderIsSet

In isolation, "HasReminder" might be used, but this can be changed to "ReminderIsSet" to allow grouping, without sacrificing grammar or readability.

Interestingly, this Microsoft example is inconsistent in that most dates are named for example "StartDate", "DueDate", but others don't follow the convention, for example "DateTimeSent" and "DateTimeCreated".